# Redirect http to https for multiple wordpress blogs running under IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, https, url-rewriting

As title stated, I've a Wordpress multisite installation running several blogs under IIS. I need to force redirect from "http" to "https" but only for some of them. Blogs are typically reachable with and without 'www'. Let's say that I have the following blogs:

- mickey.it
- donald.it
- daisy.it

and that *only* mickey and daisy run are https ready, I need a conditional rewrite condition to add to web.cofig

My web.config file has the typical Wordpress rewrite rules and not much more:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Where and which new rule to apply (avoiding broke the existing ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the url rewrite module uses regex, i'm pretty sure something like this will get you going in the right direction.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*(mickey.it|donald.it).*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Could probably get fancier with the regex here, but it should be valid in the most basic sense.

I played around with it a bit and it seemed to work...

Comment: tnx for your answer! I'll give a try...shall this rule be applied to top/botton or don't care?

Comment: I think I'd put the rule at the top. Seems like that would be the best way to enforce the redirect and then process any of your other URL permalink rules.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me! When I manually type `http://www.example.com` it doesn't redirect me to `https://www.example.com`, instead I get a `500 Error`. Any ideas? :(